# Gnome refuses switching to custom resolution

Tags: gnome, xorg, display-resolution

I've recently switched from unity to gnome. However, when I connect my second monitor and tried switching the resolution, it flashed and returned to suggested resolution instead of the one I chose.

It works with my work monitor, that doesn't require custom resolution.

My xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2384 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
  1366x768      60.00 +
  1360x768      59.80*   59.96  
  1280x720      60.00  
  1024x768      60.00  
HDMI1 connected 1024x768+1360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 192mm
  1024x768      60.00*+
  1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
  1280x1024     85.02    60.02  
  1440x900      74.98    59.90  
  1280x960      60.00  
  1360x768      60.02  
  1280x800      59.91  
  1280x720     119.99    60.00    59.94  
  720x480       60.00    59.94  
  1680x1050_60.00  59.95  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` :

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI1"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1680x1050_60.00"
EndSection
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Gnome version: GNOME Shell 3.20.4.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Edit:

I've tried running `sudo xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "1680x1050_60"`
Results in the same thing as display manager. However, if I run it twice it crashed my computer and this is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're making a minor mistake in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI1"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1680x1050_60.00"
EndSection
```

You need an extra line (real life example, not yours):

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA1"
    Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60.00"
EndSection
```

To setup the `Modeline` values you need to use:

```
cvt 1680 1050
```

copy and paste the output values to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. In addition
to the "Monitor" section you should have a "Screen" and "Device" section as well.

Reference: [Arch Linux RandR X Window System](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr)

Comment: Hey, I am afraid that did not solve the issue

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `xrandr` then `cvt 1680 1050` and finally `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`? Thanks

Comment: Yes I'll do that as soon as I get back from work.

Comment: Not sure whether adding this line helped, however, I managed to fix it by deleting  `~/.config/monitors.xml` and rebooting gnome

Comment: I also don't know enough about the internals to say if original was corrupted or regeneration from new configuration solved it. I'm glad its working though!